# Exception in 'NativeModules': java.lang.RuntimeException: Got unknown argument class: Object

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am trying to call a native `ReactMethod` from `react native` but it is throwing the following error:

> C++ Exception in 'NativeModules': java.lang.RuntimeException: Got unknown argument class: Object

This is how I have the method defined in android:

```
@ReactMethod
public void setItem(String key, Object value) {
    // code
}
```

This is how i am calling this method:

```
MyModule.setItem("mykey", "1234567890");
```

I wonder if `ReactMethod` supports object type as parameter or not? Because I want to set any type of item.

Answer (score 13):

According to the [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#argument-types), the following argument types are supported for methods annotated with *@ReactMethod*. The argument types directly map to their JavaScript equivalents.

```
Boolean -> Bool
Integer -> Number
Double -> Number
Float -> Number
String -> String
Callback -> function
ReadableMap -> Object
ReadableArray -> Array
```

In your case you could use a *[ReadableMap](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/ReadableMap.java)* as argument, which maps on the JavaScript *Object* type.

Comment: ReadableMap is for an associative array, thus it cannot be used for the other types.

Comment: was getting `ReadableNativeArray cannot be cast to *` from react, after hours understood that we have to use `ReadableArray` instead  `ReadableNativeArray`, react errors are useless and misleading

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dynamic](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/Dynamic.java) type, which is actually not documented.